# Google plus button is not working using " addthis "

Tags: google-plus

I recently use this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4ef86ce41df36324"></script>

<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```

but google plus button is not working and I found out that it is not working because I have included this code in my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
```

how to resolve this issue
thanks

Comment: The code looks like it should work to me. Could you please provide a link to the page on which you've inserted this code and it's not working?

Comment: It wasn't working back in Dec., but has worked well for awhile now, for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason that the google plus button, and also the tweet button wasn't working was because on the surrounding div I had a `margin-top: -50px;` in my CSS. As soon as this was removed then all started to work.

I changed the CSS to use `position: relative; top: -50px;` instead and it all worked.

No idea why a negative top margin should cause such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the documentation include this,

> `<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>`